# Button is not focusable because it is out of reach - tvOS Swift

Tags: swift, tvos, focus-engine

I am creating a tvOS movie browser. This view holds the movie description and displays 4 things: the movie cover image, the movie description text, a watch button, and a collection view of the movie's cast (blue boxes). The preferredFocusView is set the the watchButton. However, once I switch focus to the collection view below it, I am not able to focus on the watch button again if the cast is too short.

[The watch button is focusable here since the cast extends to just below the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAL6Q.jpg)

[The watch button IS NOT focusable here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgDRS.jpg)

Ultimately, I know I can fix it by rearranging the UI so that the watch button is directly above the first cast member, but I want to know if there is an actual way to achieve the original look I was going for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I added a focus guide to my view controller.

```
private var focusGuide: UIFocusGuide!
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
// Create focus guide
focusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)

focusGuide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.imageView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.imageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.watchButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```